# How to setup google map in react native ? facing errors

Tags: android, reactjs, google-maps, react-native

Hey i am going to install google maps in react native by following commands

```
npm install react-native-maps --save
```

But it is showing me error down below :

```
react-native-maps@0.16.2 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.40 but none was installed.
```

I have follwowing this tutorial

https://www.slideshare.net/kobkrit/reactnative-tutorial-map

Please check thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to install the newest version of `react-native-maps` and it's compatible with `react-native` >= 0.40. Upgrade your `react-native` or try to install older `react-native-maps` version. You can do that by running `npm install react-native-maps@0.12.2 --save` or even older version - check [releases](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/releases?after=v0.12.5).

Comment: I have used this provided command it is installed successfull with lower versions 

+-- react-native-maps@0.12.2 
`-- upgrade@1.1.0  extraneous

Comment: Thanks for the help